# htaccess remove variable dirt from clean url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using clean url's and mod rewrite and have encounted a small problem in parsing the string,

The clean url that works is url.com/_flie-23.html

`RewriteRule ^_file-(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newFile/$1 [L]`

however I have been getting some requests that fail such as url.com/dirt/_flie-23.html. This now misses the rewrite test. I have tried the following and it works for the /dirt/ but not the clean. any suggestions how I would do for both?

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)_file-(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newFile/$2 [L]`

**UPDATE** DoH! just needed to change to

`RewriteRule ^(.*)_file-(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newFile/$2 [L]`

Thx
Art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_file-(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newFile/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use separate rules for the clean and dirt variations:

```
RewriteRule ^_file-(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newFile/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/_file-(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newFile/$2 [L]
#                   ^----- though I think  you are missing a slash here
```

Otherwise, you can use the `?` to make a grouping optional, and changing the backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+)/)?_file-(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newFile/$3 [L]
```

Comment: this seems to fail on url.com/d/i/r/t/_file- I have updated my Q. to a rule that seems to work. - Thx Art